How to recover a disabled iPad from Ubuntu?
A friend asked me to reset their iPad to factory settings. I selected that option in the settings and screwed it up somehow. Now the device is showing:
iPad is disabled
connect to iTunes

For newer iPads, Apple offers to reset the device via icloud.com.
However, my device does not show up in "find my devices", maybe due to having iOS 14 only. It seems I'm only left with hard-resetting the iPad. The docs specifically say you need to use Windows or MacOS.
Is there a way to recover or factory reset the iPad from Ubuntu instead?
Apple obviously isn't of any help there. I have access to the associated apple account and know the previous device password. I've been googling around to find a way to do it, but didn't find any hint.
I'll now continue with the hassle of setting up a Windows machine on a spare drive, to avoid having to deal with USB pass through in a Windows VM. A Linux native way for resetting would spare a lot of effort.
I found libimobiledevice, but it seems a lot more powerful and potentially damaging than what I want to achieve. Still tried to at least use ideviceinfo from libimobiledevice-utils, but it displays "ERROR: No device found!" no matter if the USB connected device is in recovery mode or normally booted.
